# How to manage Qt5 translation files of dependent projects with CMake?

Tags: qt, cmake, qt5, qt-linguist

We have a large set of libraries, each with their translations, that is set up using CMake. For each application that uses these libraries, it scours its `TARGET_LIBRARIES` (variable set by us) for translations and combines them using `lconvert`. It also took the strings in `TARGET_LIBRARIES` to form the include paths required for the Qt translation tools to work.

I am in the process of rewriting this to use proper targets for everything. Unfortunately, I've run into difficulty when trying to get the Qt5 translations to combine all targets specified in `target_link_libraries`. previouslym all these files were gathered manually from the `TARGET_LIBRARIES` variable set in the directory (and all other thingsm like external includes, link options etc. were all set globally).

Is there a clean way to have each application get a combined `.ts` file from the `.qm` files for each CMake library/application target?